# How-To: Bootstrap 4 Inline Checkboxes - change to stack on screen size change

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I love the new setup of the checkboxes and radio buttons in Bootstrap 4, but I'd like to be able to go from "stack" to "inline" depending on the screen size. They added size tagging for so many things, but I can't find a way to do it with the new form-check and form-check-inline.

Ideally, what I'd like to do is have something like

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-left">Date Range:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="rdo30" ng-model="vm.dateRange" value="30" ng-selected="true" />
          <label for="rdo30" class="form-check-label">Last 30 Days</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="rdo90" ng-model="vm.dateRange" value="90" />
          <label for="rdo90" class="form-check-label">Last 90 Days</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="rdoYTD" ng-model="vm.dateRange" value="YTD" />
          <label for="rdoYTD" class="form-check-label">YTD</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="rdoRange" ng-model="vm.dateRange" value="range" />
          <label for="rdoRange" class="form-check-label">Manual Date Range</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but where I could change "form-check-inline" to be "form-check-inline-md" or similar - so the radio buttons would stack up until "MD" size, and then they'd go inline.

Is there anything you know of that does this in Bootstrap 4 natively, or is this not possible?

(*no, this isn't a "design" question - it's a code question. I want to know what code will help me achieve the goal.*)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap provides **Grid System**, where you can achieve responsivines by adding classes. Check the [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#offset-classes)

Comment: That does absolutely nothing to turn in-line checkboxes into a stack of them, unless your suggestion is to wrap every checkbox in a column and then tell them to stack at different resolutions? That is a very roundabout way to do the deed, and not very practical. And wrapping them in columns defeats the purpose of using Bootstrap's build-in form-check-inline classes.